# First order non-linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the solution of the following nonlinear differential equation? $\left (\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right )^2-20y+4=0$.

Comment: I have tried, but stuck at the integration $\dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{20y-4}}=dx$

Answer (score 2):

Move the square to one side and then take the square root of each side and solve.

This leads to the separable equation of this form:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5 y -1}}~dy = \pm 2\int dx$$

For the integral, let:

$$u = 5y -1 \rightarrow du = 5 dy$$

You can finish it off (recall, we have two solutions).

Comment: Nicely done! Just what was needed - +1

Answer (score 0):

$$(\frac{dy}{dx})^2-20y=-4x^0$$
this is a linear DE.

Comment: cant this be evaluated by finding the general solution and particular integral.

Comment: No, not linear, but 1st order and separable with the solution given above by @Amzoti.